# Excel report with SQL source connection

Tags: sql-server, excel, connection, report, datasource

My Excel report retrieves data from a SQL Server table using a stored procedure with parameters.

I have two connections in work book: 'A', 'B' bullet.

A. Connections in workbook

1. Query from SQL Server
2. SQL Server database connection

B. Connection on this computer

1. Connection file saved to drive `C:\Users\username\Documents\My Data Sources`

I want to send this report to business users.

What steps needs to be taken so that business users can connect to SQL Server to refresh/view report?

Comment: I believe they would need to be given access to the SQL Server. Excel passes authentication credentials to the server whenever the connection is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this two ways:

1. Like K753 said, you would need to grant each user access to the SQL server so when they open the workbook they can retrieve the data themselves.
2. I recommend using PowerQuery to pull the data and append new data to a table.  I set up a scheduled task to open, refresh the data, save, and close the workbook each night.  Then users can access or reference that excel file with no need to touch the SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Number 2 in the answer above is good. However, with the refresh options in PowerQuery you can refresh the data without even opening the workbook. Mr.Excel (Bill Jelen) has some good tutorials on this.